# fast way to tokenize data in Python like TfidfVectorizer does

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, tf-idf, stringtokenizer

i used TfidfVectoriser to create tf-idf matrix

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
transformer = TfidfVectorizer(smooth_idf=False,stop_words=stopwords.words('english'))   
tfidf = transformer.fit_transform(raw_documents=sentences)
```

Now I want to transform each element of my `sentences` list to list of tokens, which were used in tfidfvectoriser. I tried to extract it directly from `tfidf` object via this function

```
def get_token(id, transformer_name, tfidf_obj):
   return(np.array(transformer_name.get_feature_names())[\
      tfidf_obj[id].toarray().reshape((tfidf_obj.shape[1],))!=0])
```

Where `id` is index of each sentence. In this function i tried to extract given row from tf-idf object, find non-zero elements and extract corresponding elements from `transformer_name.get_feature_names()` . Looks too complex =). Also this solution works very slow =/

Is there any way to get tokens using tfidfvectorizer's preprocessing and tokenization functions?

Comment: http://www.cs.duke.edu/courses/spring14/compsci290/assignments/lab02.html

Comment: This might be useful for you?